# CORS error while calling Spring Boot Rest API from Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, cors

We are running Spring boot apps on ubuntu server. We are using Netflix Zuul as API Gateway and Eureka as Service Registry. And used Apache2 as webserver for DNS.

When I am calling the APIs from my local via jQuery Ajax, I am getting the following exception:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://*****.com/api/users' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And I can see **"Origin: null"** under **Request Headers**

**Ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
    },
    url: "https://*****.com/api/users",
    success: function(data){        
        //alert(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

To fix CORS tried following ways:
Added required config in apache:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

Added CorsMappings in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implementation class:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
}
```

Added CorsFilter bean in Zuul proxy class (annotated with @EnableZuulProxy):

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

But still same error. Any thoughts to fix this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Also, in your frontend code, in the 'headers' part of the options for your ajax call, remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, not a request header. You’re not going to fix anything by trying to set it as request header.

Comment: I already try without origin header, its not worked. HTTP response: Request Method: OPTIONS Status Code: 200 OK

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION 1:

```java
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * CORS filter for http-request and response
     */
    public CORSFilter() {
    }

    /**
     * Do Filter on every http-request.
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access_token, authorization, content-type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy method
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /**
     * Initialize CORS filter
     */
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

SOLUTION 2:

```java
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/getAnyThing")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAnyThing() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getAnyThing());
    }
```

This will resolve your endPoints

Comment: I am using Zuul API gateway. Added CORSFilter in zuul service. SOLUTION 1 is not working. I have added @CrossOrigin at api method level. But SOLUTION 2 also not working.

Answer (score 0):

The below complete class worked for me like a charm

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        // response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","yourCustomHeaderIfExist");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using API gateway Zuul. So I added above Filter in zuul service, but not working. getting same error.

Comment: in this case, there might be three potential points. The Service itself, Zuul Service (the Gateway), and the apache server.

I will try my zuul gateway for this matter, since i remember i fixed it using the above technique

Comment: aah, I have just noticed that you are putting that on Zuul Service.

No.

You just make sure that your putting this filter on the End Api Service itself, I have just tried it while Zuul Gateway service is there, and it worked perfectly

Comment: You mean to say I have to add the CORSFilter class in User service instead of Zuul Proxy service ?

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean

Comment: Not working for me. Its not showing any error in my app logs, also not hitting any service. I believe issue at apache configuration.Can you plz let me know how to add configuration on apache ?

Comment: before going into Apache, try to access the Api service through the Gateway service (zuul) - i mean bypassing the Http Server, so that you can rule anything that doesn't matter out.

However, the following link contains a good walkthrough

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Thank Ahmad, I have tried to access the api service through zuul gateway. Now I am able to access the API using ip address. But with domain name getting same error with Origin as null. How to fix ?